# powershell psobject showing as string instead of psobject, how to convert back to psobject

Tags: string, powershell, psobject

I have the following variable `$Obj` set to the following string value:

`$Obj = '@{Version=1; Name=a;}'`

How do I convert this value from a string into a custom psobject?

I would like to be able to call

`$Obj.Version` and get the value 1. Currently this call returns nothing.

Note: Due to how I am retrieving this variable, I can't initialize it without the single quotes.

Edit:

Here is the current code:

```
$Command = "script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_"
Write-Host $Command
Invoke-Expression -Command $Command
```

where `$_` is `@{Version=1; Name=a;}` (without the quote)

Originally this code was written as

`. script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_`

and worked, but when I added unit tests I changed it to use Invoke-Expression so that it could be testable with Pester unit tests. Is there a better way?

Edit2:

Turns out this can be solved by putting a back tic ` before the expression and that solves the issue for me. Thank you everyone for your input.

```
$Command = "script.ps1 -ExtraInfo `$_"
Write-Host $Command
Invoke-Expression -Command $Command
```

Comment: Please show us how `$Obj` gets generated and why you can't initialize it without single quotes.

Comment: This is indeed a strange situation that I can't help but believe it can be solved earlier in the code base

Comment: Edited my question to show more information. Thank you for your comments so far.

Comment: Not sure how pester works, never bothered on it's use, but `. script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_` was looking far better than `iex`.

Comment: When using Pester the issue with `. script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_` is that it can't be mocked and I don't want the test running this each time.

Comment: Why does it fail when using that syntax, what error message do you get?

Comment: When I execute `$Obj.Version` from `script.ps1` I get an empty value instead of the actual value.

Comment: We already know that, I'm trying to understand why does Pester not like this syntax: `. script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_` and what error it gives.

Comment: Pester will not let me mock this call, so when I run my unit tests I end up running production code in my unit test, which causes lots of issues. I need to be able to not run this script in my tests.

Comment: Someone with experience on Pester might be able to give you an alternative to what you're doing, imo there __should not__ be a need to use `iex` in any case (unless very niche). If you want to get a "coding best practice" answer I would recommend you to add your Pester code as well as minimal example of `script.ps1` (at least it's `param(...)` block). In addition, add the [tag:pester] tag to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, this is odd, and should be resolved earlier in the code base. However, if that is not possible, use `Invoke-Expression`

like so

```
$newObj = Invoke-Expression $Obj
```

[Further reading on Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2#description)

Comment: If `$Obj` is a string with content `'@{Version=1; Name=a;}'`, your `Invoke-Expression` call fails, because (a) it'll try to parse the string as a _hashtable literal_, not a `[pscustomobject]`,  and (b), more importantly, `a` is interpreted as a _command to execute_, not a string. To put it differently: You cannot robustly re-create a `[pscustomobject]` instance from its stringified representation. Also, using `Invoke-Expression` this way is a security risk.

Answer (score 1):

**The stringified version of a `[pscustomobject]` instance, which *resembles* a hashtable literal, is *not* suitable for programmatic processing**, as the following example demonstrates:

```sh
# Stringify a [pscustomobject] instance.
PS> "$([pscsutomobject] @{ Version=1; Name='a value' })" 

@{Version=1; Name=a value}  # !! Quoting of the .Name value was lost
```

The problem gets worse for property values that are themselves complex objects.

---

Since you do appear to have access to the original `[pscustomobject]` instance, **the solution is *not* to stringify**.

For that, you simply need to avoid *up-front* string interpolation by using a [*verbatim* (single-quoted) string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) (`'...'`) and letting [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) -  [which should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375) - interpret the `$_` variable as its original type:

```sh
# Use *single* quotes to prevent up-front expansion.
$Command = 'script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $_'
Write-Host $Command
Invoke-Expression -Command $Command
```

Note that the use of a *verbatim* (non-interpolating) string literal makes the use of `Invoke-Expression` safe here, though, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out, **there may be a better alternatives in general, and particularly in the context of Pester**.

A **[*script-block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)-based solution** (`{ ... }`) that receives the object *as an argument*:

```sh
$Command = { script.ps1 -ExtraInfo $args[0] }
Write-Host "Calling { $Command } with argument $_"
. $Command $_
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with `Name=a` because `a` is not a known object (or at least not defined in my PS Session). But if this is a string, this can be done with the following script:

```
$Obj = '@{Version=1; Name="a";}'
$s= [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create("New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Obj")
$o = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $s
$o.Version
```

Comment: I ran into this as well, but I assume those are just placeholder values.